# Heroku doesn't show anything

Tags: php, heroku

In my localhost the program runs well, but when I deploy it to heroku it doesn't show anything [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEKJC.png) and this is my folder [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xxAh.png). Here my index code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ina">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lovanto Blog</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/modal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'cloudinary/vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'cloudinary/config.php';

    include 'conn.php';
    include 'code/clock.php';
    include 'view/header.php';
    include 'view/body.php';
    include 'view/footer.php';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

Comment: Try on webserver change all path with `./allpath/`

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Example `include 'view/footer.php';` to  `include './view/footer.php';` obv with all path

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: You change all include/require file? Have you check google dev if all file is included?

Comment: still same with the blank one

Comment: No php error? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` use this code for see if it's all ok

Comment: Why are you doing all that includes when you are using an autoloader?